# How to move popup's around the window JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, properties

I am trying to move a pop-up window around the browser, I have used the moveTo and setInterval function to move it slowly.

I just don't understand how to use the moveTo function in this case

```
let ventana=null;
let move;
let x=0;
let y=1;

function openWindow() {
  ventana = window.open(
    "http://intranet.my/ventana.html",
    "DescriptiveWindowName",
    "resizable,scrollbars,status,width=200px,height=200px"
  );
}

function moveWindow(){
    clearInterval(move);
    move = setInterval(function() { moveRight(); }, 2);
}

function moveRight(){
    ventana.moveTo(x,y);
    x=y;
    y++;
    console.log("x: "+x+" // "+"y: "+y)
}
```

Comment: You didn't give any value to `x` and `y` in `ventana.moveTo(x,y)`. Give some value to the variable which will then move the window.

Comment: You have two functions called `moveWindow`, which is an error, and you're not calling `moveWindow()` anywhere. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/nfjeLckp/

Comment: yes it works, but  the question is down -> right -> up ->left (loop)